# How do I disable checkboxes after a number of checkbox selected?

Tags: android, android-studio, checkbox

I have 10 checkboxes and I want to disable the remaining checkbox after a maximum of 6 checkboxes selected.

How do I use `OnCheckChangedListener` to solve the problem.

If I write the code as below, I need to repeat it 10 times

```
checkbox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    if (isChecked && numberOfCheckboxesChecked >= 6) {
        checkbox1.setChecked(false);
    } else {
    }
}};
```

How should I do to reduce redundant code?

Comment: You need to maintain a list of boolean to check whether check box is selected or not.

Comment: @UserSharma can I have an example ? I'm a newbie, I don't really understand

Answer (score 0):

You can create a named class instead of an anonymous class:

```
checkbox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new MyCheckboxChangeListener());
checkbox2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new MyCheckboxChangeListener());
...

private static class MyCheckboxChangeListener implements OnCheckedChangeListener {

    private static int numberOfCheckboxesChecked;

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            if (numberOfCheckboxesChecked >= 6) {
                buttonView.setChecked(false);
            } else {
                numberOfCheckboxesChecked++;
            }
        } else {
            numberOfCheckboxesChecked--;            
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can implement the interface in your Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnCheckedChangeListener {

    ...
    private int numberOfCheckboxesChecked;
    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        checkbox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        checkbox2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        if (isChecked) {
            if (numberOfCheckboxesChecked >= 6) {
                buttonView.setChecked(false);
            } else {
                numberOfCheckboxesChecked++;
            }
        } else {
            numberOfCheckboxesChecked--;            
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: after I create a class, then I just implement the function in my activity ??

Comment: I'm not sure of what you're asking. However, the approach I exemplified is a [Nested class](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_innerclasses.htm). As you said, you can also implement this listener in your activity. In that case, you would use `checkbox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this)` and your activity would have the `onCheckedChanged` method.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include you suggestion. Also, I've corrected the logic.

Comment: Perhaps you implemented the wrong interface. Try implementing `CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener`